# Appending a value from one list, given an index value from another list

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

I am currently have two lists one has types of precipitation and one has the amounts of precipitation. I want to generate a new list that has the amount of precipitation for the value snow. I am trying to write and for loop + if/else statement that will iterate threw the list of types of precipitation and if the type is "Snow" than will append the amount of precipitation to another list, given the index position of where it says snow.

```
My two lists are :
precip = ['Precip', 'Precip', 'Precip', 'Precip', 'Precip', 'Precip', 'Precip', 'Snow', 'Snow', 'Precip']

amt = ['0.03 in', '0.19 in', '0.8 in', '0 in', '0 in', '0 in', '0 in', '0.2 in', '1.3 in', '-- in']
```

So as my fx iterates through the list precip, any time is sees snow I want it to append the value from the amt list that matches that index position of snow in the precip list, to a new list.

My code is as followed:

precip = ['Precip', 'Precip', 'Precip', 'Precip', 'Precip', 'Precip', 'Precip', 'Snow', 'Snow', 'Precip']

amt = ['0.03 in', '0.19 in', '0.8 in', '0 in', '0 in', '0 in', '0 in', '0.2 in', '1.3 in', '-- in']

```
[IN]:
snow = [ ]
i = 0

for n in precip:
     if n == "Snow"
          snow.append(amt[n])
     i  +=0

[OUT]:

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Can someone help me correct this so I will have a new list snow = ['0.02 in', '1.3 in']

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of your code is correct except iterate using the index rather on the elements of the `precip` list.

```
precip = ['Precip', 'Precip', 'Precip', 'Precip', 'Precip', 'Precip', 'Precip', 'Snow', 'Snow', 'Precip']

amt = ['0.03 in', '0.19 in', '0.8 in', '0 in', '0 in', '0 in', '0 in', '0.2 in', '1.3 in', '-- in']

snow = []

for i in range(len(precip)):
    if precip[i] == "Snow":
        snow.append(amt[i])

print(snow)
```

Output:

```
['0.2 in', '1.3 in']
```

OR

you can use `enumerate` on the `precip` list to get the element and index of the element while iterating.

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices.

(1.) [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to combine parallel arrays

```
for p, a in zip(precip, amt):
    print(p, a)
```

(2.) index into parallel arrays

```
for i, p in enumerate(precip):
    assert p == precip[i]
    print(i, p, amt[i])
```

(You could also do (3.) `for i in range(len(precip)):`,
or (4.) an equivalent `while` loop, but `enumerate` is clearer.)

Once that debug `print` has made it clear to you
that they're being accessed in parallel,
then just do the obvious, e.g.

```
for p, a in zip(precip, amt):
    if p == 'Snow':
        snow.append(a)
```

---

Consider renaming your containers so they are plural: `precips` and `amts`.
That frees up a singular name to hold a scalar:

```
for precip, amt in zip(precips, amts):
```